# Multiline label with both sides images

Tags: ios, swift

Can we able to set the multiline label with left and right side as image. please check the attached image.

Yes, I am using tableview cell xib. Need to do this with constraints.

[image]

I tried
left imageview - leading, width, height, vertically in container

second label - top, bottom , leading to first image , trailing to second image. number of lines = 0.

right image view embed with UIView - this is for when select the image background colour changed to blue with checkmark image
constraint - trailing, width , height , vertically in container

**The issue is label is getting truncated when large text is there.**

After that,I tried to remove the width of second image, but getting constraint issue.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thankyou in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell can be prevented from performing dynamic auto-resizing for a variety of reasons:

1. **Constraints could be preventing dynamic height:**

   To confirm the constraints, run the app in the debugger, then tap on the “Debug View Hierarchy” button and confirm the constraints. It is a quick way to see all the constraints (and make sure there are not any that you did not intend):

   [image]

   If you had some extraneous constraint (e.g., an unintended height combined with top/bottom), that could cause the label to not grow in height to fit the text.
2. **The table view could be defined to not support automatic dimension of the cells:**

   Another possible source of the problem is the table view’s row height was set to some fixed value, preventing the label from expanding to fit the text. Confirm that the table view’s row height is set to `automaticDimension`. Either in IB:

   [image]

   Or, programmatically:

   ```swift
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")

       tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
       tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
   }
   ```
3. **You could have something in code that is forcing a particular cell height:**

   Needless to say, make sure you are not implementing a specific height in [`tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview). The use of `automaticDimension`, above, means that you should not implement this delegate method at all.
4. **Maybe the number of lines is getting reset to 1.**

   While in the view debugger, look at the properties for the label, and make sure the `numberOfLines` is still set to zero. Make sure there isn’t some code somewhere that is resetting the `numberOfLines`.

   [image]

---

Not that it is relevant, but this is the code that generated the above image. Not much here to see, admittedly:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var strings = [
        "This is a very long string that goes on and on. This is so long that it will take a few lines. This one takes four lines, but the next one takes only one.",
        "This is short string.",
        "This is a very long string that goes on and on."
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return strings.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.customLabel.text = strings[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this. this is very helpful.
But I need to keep the left and right image as constant height.
Only label needs to change the dynamic height as per the test length.

However when I keep the image height as constant it is not allowing label to give as dynamic height.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’ve done. Constant height images, dynamic height label.

Comment: I found my mistake. Now it is working fine.
Thankyou very much for your help.